# AsyncTast onPostExecute Not Updating UI elements : Throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I m stuck in the problem from a time.
this is my code

```
public class PilgrimFriendActivity extends Activity {

    private String DOMAIN = "http://";

    private String LAWS_URL = "";
    private String LOCATIONS_URL = "";

    private ListView list;
    private TextView content;
    private Law law  ;
    private Location location;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("com.hackontech.pilgrim_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.DOMAIN += preferences.getString("DOMAIN","192.168.0.104");
        this.LAWS_URL = DOMAIN + "/pilgrimfriend/main/getAllLaws";
        this.LOCATIONS_URL = DOMAIN + "/pilgrimfriend/main/getAllLocations";

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.laws);
        this.lLaws();

    }


    public void lLaws() {

        final class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            private String URL = null;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
                String result = null;
                URL = uri[0];
                try {

                    //Create default http client
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                    Log.v("URL",URL);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    //Retrieve the response body or "entity"
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    //Return the entity as String
                    result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    Log.v("result",result.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return e.getMessage();
                }

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //super.onPostExecute(result);
                dialog.dismiss();
                try{

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    JSONObject json_data;
                    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int i=0; i < jArray.length() ; i++) {
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id=json_data.getInt("id");
                        String title=json_data.getString("title");
                        String scholor =json_data.getString("scholor");
                        items.add(title+" ("+scholor+")");
                    }

                    content.setText(result);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),  
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                    list.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                catch(JSONException e) {
                    //content.setText(e.getMessage());
                }
                //Do anything with response..
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();

                dialog.setTitle("Downloading Laws Data");
                dialog.show();
            }

        }

        new RequestTask().execute(LAWS_URL);
    }
```

I every single method is working but in `onPostExecute` when i change the view elements like i did `content.setText(result)`, the application stops immediately, what's the problem.

here is the `LogCat`:

```
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at com.hackontech.pilgrim.PilgrimFriendActivity$1RequestTask.onPostExecute(PilgrimFriendActivity.java:120)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at com.hackontech.pilgrim.PilgrimFriendActivity$1RequestTask.onPostExecute(PilgrimFriendActivity.java:1)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-07 22:44:33.302: E/AndroidRuntime(778):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I guess `content` is null. did you initialize it?

Comment: Yeah i did, i can update it anywhere else, not only the content, the listview is also not working, in short it's not updating the UI, but the strange part is that the process dialog is showing, the Toast does display

Comment: add `Crash logs` and the line number. `dialog` is showing or dismiss?

Comment: dialog is dismissed, let me post complete code

Comment: @user868900 Exception backtrace in the log tells you exact line number where the exception was thrown, why not simply check what's going on there? How about placing a breakpoint there and running your application under debugger control? It's all basic stuff.

Comment: @user868900 :try after  commenting this line` content.setText(result);` and set it to  `content.setText("user868900");` .then check what happening in logcat

Comment: I just want to know, why i can't update UI elements in this method onPostExecute.... doesn't matter what data i want to fill in.

Comment: @user868900 : use `TextView content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content); content.setText("user868900");` instead of `content.setText("user868900");` in `onPostExecute` and just check what happening because you are free to access any ui element inside onPostExecute . may be possible you are not using right layout for Activity  in setContentView so make sure you are using right layout that's main.xml in res/layout in which you have `content textView `or other elements

Comment: @user868900 : any success !!!

Comment: m completely transfering code to another project, wait for my signal

Comment: Most importantly: mark which line is 120! If I understand correctly, line 120 is `content.setText(result);`. If so check in onCreate before calling  that `content` and `list` do exist (you might have broken layout xml). Additionally check that `json_data` is always non-null as it might be just such data.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `onPostExecute` method does all the UI updates at once, when the method has finished.

For example:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {
    someTextView.setText("Do In Background Finished!");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute () {
    someTextView.setText("Post Execute Started");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ..
    }
    someTextView.setText("Post Execute Finished");
}
```

will result in showing "Do In Background Finished!" and after 5 seconds (when `onPostExecute` ends) will update the text with "Post Execute Started" and immediately updates the text again with "Post Execute Finished".